# flask CSP ( Content-Security-Policy ) best practice against attack such as cross site scripting

Tags: flask, jinja2, content-security-policy

I am new to CSP. I am trying to implement CSP in all my templates in my flask app by setting the resp_header to protect my website from Cross-Site Scripting attacks. I modified my render template from:

```
return render_template('addvideos.html'  form=form, legend = 'Update video : '+ videos.video_name)
```

to

```
    resp = make_response(render_template('addvideos.html', legend = 'Update video : '+ videos.video_name)
)
    resp.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self';"
    return resp
```

I have more than 50 "render_template" in the app and I will have to add a response header for each. After research, I found out that after_request will do the trick as shown below:

```
@app.after_request
def add_security_headers(resp):
    resp.headers['Content-Security-Policy']='default-src \'self\''
    return resp
```

is this very reliable? What if I apply the CSP directly in the HTML template ( jinja2 ), is that possible? Which is more reliable?

Comment: did you manage to use nonce that way? I am struggling to get the nonce value in the html template..

Comment: as well why using "\'self\''" and response.headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = "default-src 'self'" without escaping like doc says? tx for the help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is this very reliable ?

Yes.  Setting that header within the `app.after_request` decorator applies the header to all routes served by that `app`.

> What if I apply the CSP directly in the HTML template ( jinja2 ), is that possible?

Not something that can be done in the template itself, you'd set that header within Python as above.

> Which is more reliable ?

Whilst the former method (via the `app.after_request` decorator) works, it's commonly something that can be handled by the reverse proxy which your Python app server sits behind.  If that's unfamiliar, have a look at [the deployment docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/).

For example with nginx as a reverse proxy you could put this in your `server` block:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
```

Or, to send the header regardless of response code:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" always;
```

[This blog](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/nginx/) has some good advice on whether to let the reverse proxy handle sending this header, or define it in your Flask app:

> **Should I add a CSP header with nginx or my in application?**
> While it is certainly easy to add a CSP header with nginx, it also possible to add a `Content-Security-Policy` header with your server side programming language ([Flask]). There are tradeoffs to doing it either way. If you have sections of your application that may require a different CSP policy then it might be easier to use your application programming language instead. Or if you plan to use features such as a [CSP nonce](https://content-security-policy.com/nonce/), then it is much easier to set the `Content-Security-Policy` from your application code instead of from nginx.

Also if you're deploying to a platform like Heroku, which in a basic configuration exposes the gunicorn app server directly, then it's probably eaiser to set this header in your app, unless you plan to go further and deploy an nginx buildpack.

Other cloud based load balancers may provide their own way to set these headers, independent of your app.

When configuring a reverse proxy or load balacner it's worth a look at [Mozilla's SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/) which supports nginx, AWS ALB/ELB and others.  The server can then be tested with [Qualys SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time writing this. Its very helpful

Comment: In case. I am using the same technic but as well trying to pas a nonce, but don't seem to be able to access the nonce value from html template.